# How do I dynamically create webpages and automatically cycle through them using MVC and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dashboard that has a horizontal list of user created accordion items. I want to check the database and if there are more than 8 items, create a new page.

For example:
There are currently 8 accordion items on the page, a user creates a 9th accordion item, this 9th item populates a new page with that item. The program then automatically cycles through these pages.

This process repeats indefinitely, populating each page with up to 8 items.

My question is, how do I dynamically create webpages using MVC, depending on the size of a database and automatically cycle through them?

Comment: Why not just use a grid control with pagination? Or pass a querystring parameter? There are plenty of options to do that. It would also be helpful to show your code so we know exactly what you're dealing with. Not much information at the moment.

Comment: I have never heard of grid control with pagination. I have an index method in my home controller that does a an sqlquery and sets it to a model then passes that model to the view. I loop through the model in the view and set the data to accordion items.

Comment: Most grid controls have pagination... Also, there are a lot of javascript samples out there that will add pagination to your accordians. They're usually pretty extendable and the page size is usually just a setting. Yes, SQL query returning a list of results to your client and then you're looping through them and writing out your HTML. Probably within a div. Do a search there are tons of examples. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=accordian+pagination+javascript

Comment: I got it working with pagedList, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Still trying to figure out how to auto cycle through the pages.

Comment: Not having luck on this, any advise on how to loop through the pages without human interaction?

Comment: Well, nobody can really help you until you post your code.